# Sonarqube Login Issues Windows Service

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

Cant login to Sonar web and I have created a sonar database in PostgresSQL to connect. I can't even login as an admin and I have reset the admin password. Anyone have an idea on what's going on?

Here are my sonar properties:  # User credentials.

## Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.

sonar username =sonarqube
sonar password =mypassword
I'm using PostgreSQL so I enabled that part of the properties file

sonar.web.host=(made this my IP address) and I enabled the default port 9000

The soar log/web is not telling me much apart from an authentication failed. I think my problem is PostgreSQL  as the logs there are telling me this below

2017-12-07 11:02:37 CST LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-12-07 11:02:35 CST
2017-12-07 11:02:37 CST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-12-07 11:02:37 CST LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-12-07 11:02:37 CST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2017-12-07 11:02:37 CST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-12-07 11:02:38 CST FATAL:  role "ins5754" does not exist

I'm not sure why PostgreSQL  is not  running as the admin user "postgres" which is what I specified as when I first installed it.

Comment: Please add more information : what is the error ? what is your sonar.properties configuration file ? And please add sonar.log, web.log to your question.

Comment: Has the user you use "dbo"-rights in the  PostgresSQL SonarQube database?